# Should I directly use pre-built codes on Github?

Tags: programming-practices, github, junior-programmer

I need to know if is it correct to use pre-built codes on Github, or try to build it my self, while even I tried to build it I think it won't be as proffissional as that one on Github... the point is that I don't like to use pre-built codes but this consumes me, which I think I won't be a proffissional programmer by time if I depend on Github cods, or any other pre-builts...so what to do?

Comment: every programmer depends on libraries and code fragments he finds elsewhere to a degree. As long as you mention sources and don't violate licenses, nothing wrong with looking at how others have solved a problem in the past. It's a great way to learn and improve yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the one hand, you're not going to learn as much by using pre-existing code as by writing it yourself.  On the other hand, programmers use libraries for a reason, and you can't learn about every aspect of programming simultaneously.

Personally, I'd say that whatever the primary focus of your program is, you should write it yourself (you may want to look at other's code for comparison as well), but for other aspects of the program that you're not currently focusing on (storage, UI, whatever) it's fine to use pre-existing code.

That said, you may as well maximize your learning by going through any added code line by line to understand how it's written, time permitting.